# How parse XML file to give the Key as an XPath and Value as the actual value (Map data structure?)

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have this XML file (example.xml):

```
<PayrollFormInfo xmlns="http://www.irs.com/PayrollFormInfo/2004">
    <FormInfo>
        <ExportDataVersion>100</ExportDataVersion>
        <QBVersion>IFSP</QBVersion>
        <FormSetID>FSDYF</FormSetID>
        <FormID>INWKS941</FormID>
        <FormDesc>Quarterly Federal Tax Return</FormDesc>
        <FormFilingPeriod>Quarterly</FormFilingPeriod>
        <TotalsBreakoutBy>Daily</TotalsBreakoutBy>
        <BeginDate>01/01/2015</BeginDate>
        <EndDate>03/31/2015</EndDate>
        <EFYes>true</EFYes>
        <IncludeInstructionSheet>false</IncludeInstructionSheet>
    </FormInfo>
    <CompanyInfo>
        <CompanyName>PatsFedTaxSemiWeekly20144QRT_CT</CompanyName>
        <LegalName>P #a(9t)-'&amp;sFedTaxSemiWeekly2014_4QRTCT</LegalName>
        <EmployerID>507754170</EmployerID>
        <IntuitPayrollServiceID>1862684</IntuitPayrollServiceID>
        <LegalAddressLine1>Def-ault/ .String</LegalAddressLine1>
        <LegalCity>St. Louis</LegalCity>
        <LegalState>CB</LegalState>
        <LegalZip>06300-0987</LegalZip>
        <MailingAddressLine1>Default String Addr</MailingAddressLine1>
        <MailingCity>Greenwich</MailingCity>
        <MailingState>CT</MailingState>
        <MailingZip>06830</MailingZip>
        <NumberOfEmployees>2</NumberOfEmployees>
        <FWTDepositFrequency>SEMI_WEEKLY</FWTDepositFrequency>
        <ExemptFlag>false</ExemptFlag>
        <EmployerType>Contributing</EmployerType>
        <FUTAExemptFlag>false</FUTAExemptFlag>
        <FederalTotals>
            <PeriodBeginDate>01/01/2015</PeriodBeginDate>
            <PeriodEndDate>01/01/2015</PeriodEndDate>
            <GrossPay>0.00</GrossPay>
            <NetPay>0.00</NetPay>
            <SocialSecurityWages>15384.62</SocialSecurityWages>
            <SocialSecurityLiability>-10.10</SocialSecurityLiability>
            <MedicareWages>15384.62</MedicareWages>
            <MedicareLiability>-1.01</MedicareLiability>
            <FederalWages>13076.92</FederalWages>
            <FederalWithholding>-101.00</FederalWithholding>
            <TaxableFUTAWages>0.00</TaxableFUTAWages>
            <TotalFUTAWages>0.00</TotalFUTAWages>
            <FUTALiability>0.00</FUTALiability>
            <EIC>0.00</EIC>
            <SocialSecurityTips>1.01</SocialSecurityTips>
        </FederalTotals>
        <FederalTotals>
            <PeriodBeginDate>01/02/2015</PeriodBeginDate>
            <PeriodEndDate>01/02/2015</PeriodEndDate>
            <GrossPay>0.00</GrossPay>
            <NetPay>0.00</NetPay>
            <SocialSecurityWages>15384.62</SocialSecurityWages>
            <SocialSecurityLiability>-10.20</SocialSecurityLiability>
            <MedicareWages>15384.62</MedicareWages>
            <MedicareLiability>-1.02</MedicareLiability>
            <FederalWages>13076.92</FederalWages>
            <FederalWithholding>-102.00</FederalWithholding>
            <TaxableFUTAWages>0.00</TaxableFUTAWages>
            <TotalFUTAWages>0.00</TotalFUTAWages>
            <FUTALiability>0.00</FUTALiability>
            <EIC>0.00</EIC>
            <SocialSecurityTips>1.02</SocialSecurityTips>
        </FederalTotals>
        <TaxItemTotals>
            <PeriodBeginDate>01/01/2015</PeriodBeginDate>
            <PeriodEndDate>03/31/2015</PeriodEndDate>
            <TaxTableID>200</TaxTableID>
            <TotalWagesAndTips>0.00</TotalWagesAndTips>
            <TaxableWagesAndTips>164615.44</TaxableWagesAndTips>
            <TaxAmount>0.00</TaxAmount>
        </TaxItemTotals>
        <PaymentInfo>
            <PeriodBeginDate>01/14/2015</PeriodBeginDate>
            <PeriodEndDate>01/16/2015</PeriodEndDate>
            <TaxTableID>62</TaxTableID>
            <Amount>953.86</Amount>
            <PaymentDate>04/03/2015</PaymentDate>
        </PaymentInfo>
        <EmpsWorked>
            <TaxTableID>63</TaxTableID>
            <TestDate>3/12/2015</TestDate>
            <NumEmps>2</NumEmps>
        </EmpsWorked>
        <EmpSummary>
            <EmployeeID>4514230</EmployeeID>
            <FirstName>JillCT</FirstName>
            <MiddleInitial>S</MiddleInitial>
            <LastName>Taylor</LastName>
            <SSN>150-86-6794</SSN>
            <IsStatutory>false</IsStatutory>
            <HasPensionPlan>false</HasPensionPlan>
            <EmployeeType>REGULAR</EmployeeType>
        </EmpSummary>
        <EmpSummary>
            <EmployeeID>4514229</EmployeeID>
            <FirstName>JoseCT</FirstName>
            <MiddleInitial>S</MiddleInitial>
            <LastName>George</LastName>
            <SSN>792-93-6215</SSN>
            <IsStatutory>false</IsStatutory>
            <HasPensionPlan>false</HasPensionPlan>
            <EmployeeType>REGULAR</EmployeeType>
        </EmpSummary>
        <FederalReturnType>941</FederalReturnType>
    </CompanyInfo>
    <EmployeeInfo>
        <EmployeeType>REGULAR</EmployeeType>
        <EmployeeID>4514230</EmployeeID>
        <FirstName>JillCT</FirstName>
        <MiddleInitial>S</MiddleInitial>
        <LastName>Taylor</LastName>
        <SSN>150-86-6794</SSN>
        <HireDate>10/09/2009</HireDate>
        <IsStatutory>false</IsStatutory>
        <HasPensionPlan>false</HasPensionPlan>
        <NumberOfExemptions>0</NumberOfExemptions>
        <StateLived>CT</StateLived>
        <StateWorked>CT</StateWorked>
        <Gender>F</Gender>
        <AddressLine1>123 default St.</AddressLine1>
        <City>Greenwich</City>
        <State>CT</State>
        <ZipCode>06830</ZipCode>
        <FederalTotals>
            <PeriodBeginDate>01/01/2015</PeriodBeginDate>
            <PeriodEndDate>01/31/2015</PeriodEndDate>
            <GrossPay>0.00</GrossPay>
            <NetPay>0.00</NetPay>
            <SocialSecurityWages>49269.21</SocialSecurityWages>
            <SocialSecurityLiability>-3054.69</SocialSecurityLiability>
            <MedicareWages>50769.24</MedicareWages>
            <MedicareLiability>-736.16</MedicareLiability>
            <FederalWages>46153.84</FederalWages>
            <FederalWithholding>-14242.77</FederalWithholding>
            <TaxableFUTAWages>0.00</TaxableFUTAWages>
            <TotalFUTAWages>0.00</TotalFUTAWages>
            <FUTALiability>0.00</FUTALiability>
            <EIC>0.00</EIC>
            <SocialSecurityTips>0.00</SocialSecurityTips>
        </FederalTotals>
        <FederalTotals>
            <PeriodBeginDate>02/01/2015</PeriodBeginDate>
            <PeriodEndDate>02/28/2015</PeriodEndDate>
            <GrossPay>0.00</GrossPay>
            <NetPay>0.00</NetPay>
            <SocialSecurityWages>15384.62</SocialSecurityWages>
            <SocialSecurityLiability>-953.85</SocialSecurityLiability>
            <MedicareWages>35384.62</MedicareWages>
            <MedicareLiability>-513.08</MedicareLiability>
            <FederalWages>33076.92</FederalWages>
            <FederalWithholding>-10637.87</FederalWithholding>
            <TaxableFUTAWages>0.00</TaxableFUTAWages>
            <TotalFUTAWages>0.00</TotalFUTAWages>
            <FUTALiability>0.00</FUTALiability>
            <EIC>0.00</EIC>
            <SocialSecurityTips>0.00</SocialSecurityTips>
        </FederalTotals>
        <FederalTotals>
            <PeriodBeginDate>03/01/2015</PeriodBeginDate>
            <PeriodEndDate>03/31/2015</PeriodEndDate>
            <GrossPay>0.00</GrossPay>
            <NetPay>0.00</NetPay>
            <SocialSecurityWages>46153.86</SocialSecurityWages>
            <SocialSecurityLiability>-2861.54</SocialSecurityLiability>
            <MedicareWages>196153.86</MedicareWages>
            <MedicareLiability>-3654.22</MedicareLiability>
            <FederalWages>189230.76</FederalWages>
            <FederalWithholding>-68440.64</FederalWithholding>
            <TaxableFUTAWages>0.00</TaxableFUTAWages>
            <TotalFUTAWages>0.00</TotalFUTAWages>
            <FUTALiability>0.00</FUTALiability>
            <EIC>0.00</EIC>
            <SocialSecurityTips>0.00</SocialSecurityTips>
        </FederalTotals>
        <WorkedInfo>
            <TaxTableID>64</TaxTableID>
            <TestDate>01/12/2015</TestDate>
            <Worked>true</Worked>
        </WorkedInfo>
        <WorkedInfo>
            <TaxTableID>62</TaxTableID>
            <TestDate>02/12/2015</TestDate>
            <Worked>true</Worked>
        </WorkedInfo>
        <WorkedInfo>
            <TaxTableID>61</TaxTableID>
            <TestDate>01/12/2015</TestDate>
            <Worked>true</Worked>
        </WorkedInfo>
        <WorkedInfo>
            <TaxTableID>61</TaxTableID>
            <TestDate>02/12/2015</TestDate>
            <Worked>true</Worked>
        </WorkedInfo>
        <WorkedInfo>
            <TaxTableID>1</TaxTableID>
            <TestDate>02/12/2015</TestDate>
            <Worked>true</Worked>
        </WorkedInfo>
        <WorkedInfo>
            <TaxTableID>1</TaxTableID>
            <TestDate>03/12/2015</TestDate>
            <Worked>true</Worked>
        </WorkedInfo>
        <WorkedInfo>
            <TaxTableID>62</TaxTableID>
            <TestDate>03/12/2015</TestDate>
            <Worked>true</Worked>
        </WorkedInfo>
        <WorkedInfo>
            <TaxTableID>63</TaxTableID>
            <TestDate>02/12/2015</TestDate>
            <Worked>true</Worked>
        </WorkedInfo>
        <WorkedInfo>
            <TaxTableID>61</TaxTableID>
            <TestDate>03/12/2015</TestDate>
            <Worked>true</Worked>
        </WorkedInfo>
        <WorkedInfo>
            <TaxTableID>64</TaxTableID>
            <TestDate>02/12/2015</TestDate>
            <Worked>true</Worked>
        </WorkedInfo>
        <WorkedInfo>
            <TaxTableID>63</TaxTableID>
            <TestDate>03/12/2015</TestDate>
            <Worked>true</Worked>
        </WorkedInfo>
        <WorkedInfo>
            <TaxTableID>62</TaxTableID>
            <TestDate>01/12/2015</TestDate>
            <Worked>true</Worked>
        </WorkedInfo>
        <WorkedInfo>
            <TaxTableID>64</TaxTableID>
            <TestDate>03/12/2015</TestDate>
            <Worked>true</Worked>
        </WorkedInfo>
        <WorkedInfo>
            <TaxTableID>63</TaxTableID>
            <TestDate>01/12/2015</TestDate>
            <Worked>true</Worked>
        </WorkedInfo>
        <WorkedInfo>
            <TaxTableID>1</TaxTableID>
            <TestDate>01/12/2015</TestDate>
            <Worked>true</Worked>
        </WorkedInfo>
    </EmployeeInfo>
    <EmployeeInfo>
        <EmployeeType>REGULAR</EmployeeType>
        <EmployeeID>4514229</EmployeeID>
        <FirstName>JoseCT</FirstName>
        <MiddleInitial>S</MiddleInitial>
        <LastName>George</LastName>
        <SSN>792-93-6215</SSN>
        <HireDate>10/09/2009</HireDate>
        <IsStatutory>false</IsStatutory>
        <HasPensionPlan>false</HasPensionPlan>
        <NumberOfExemptions>0</NumberOfExemptions>
        <StateLived>CT</StateLived>
        <StateWorked>CT</StateWorked>
        <Gender>M</Gender>
        <AddressLine1>123 default St.</AddressLine1>
        <City>Greenwich</City>
        <State>CT</State>
        <ZipCode>06830</ZipCode>
        <FederalTotals>
            <PeriodBeginDate>02/01/2015</PeriodBeginDate>
            <PeriodEndDate>02/28/2015</PeriodEndDate>
            <GrossPay>0.00</GrossPay>
            <NetPay>0.00</NetPay>
            <SocialSecurityWages>15384.62</SocialSecurityWages>
            <SocialSecurityLiability>-953.85</SocialSecurityLiability>
            <MedicareWages>35384.62</MedicareWages>
            <MedicareLiability>-513.08</MedicareLiability>
            <FederalWages>33076.92</FederalWages>
            <FederalWithholding>-10637.87</FederalWithholding>
            <TaxableFUTAWages>0.00</TaxableFUTAWages>
            <TotalFUTAWages>0.00</TotalFUTAWages>
            <FUTALiability>0.00</FUTALiability>
            <EIC>0.00</EIC>
            <SocialSecurityTips>0.00</SocialSecurityTips>
        </FederalTotals>
        <FederalTotals>
            <PeriodBeginDate>01/01/2015</PeriodBeginDate>
            <PeriodEndDate>01/31/2015</PeriodEndDate>
            <GrossPay>0.00</GrossPay>
            <NetPay>0.00</NetPay>
            <SocialSecurityWages>49269.21</SocialSecurityWages>
            <SocialSecurityLiability>-3054.69</SocialSecurityLiability>
            <MedicareWages>50769.24</MedicareWages>
            <MedicareLiability>-736.16</MedicareLiability>
            <FederalWages>46153.84</FederalWages>
            <FederalWithholding>-14242.77</FederalWithholding>
            <TaxableFUTAWages>0.00</TaxableFUTAWages>
            <TotalFUTAWages>0.00</TotalFUTAWages>
            <FUTALiability>0.00</FUTALiability>
            <EIC>0.00</EIC>
            <SocialSecurityTips>0.00</SocialSecurityTips>
        </FederalTotals>
        <FederalTotals>
            <PeriodBeginDate>03/01/2015</PeriodBeginDate>
            <PeriodEndDate>03/31/2015</PeriodEndDate>
            <GrossPay>0.00</GrossPay>
            <NetPay>0.00</NetPay>
            <SocialSecurityWages>46153.86</SocialSecurityWages>
            <SocialSecurityLiability>-2861.54</SocialSecurityLiability>
            <MedicareWages>196153.86</MedicareWages>
            <MedicareLiability>-3654.22</MedicareLiability>
            <FederalWages>189230.76</FederalWages>
            <FederalWithholding>-68440.64</FederalWithholding>
            <TaxableFUTAWages>0.00</TaxableFUTAWages>
            <TotalFUTAWages>0.00</TotalFUTAWages>
            <FUTALiability>0.00</FUTALiability>
            <EIC>0.00</EIC>
            <SocialSecurityTips>0.00</SocialSecurityTips>
        </FederalTotals>
        <WorkedInfo>
            <TaxTableID>63</TaxTableID>
            <TestDate>03/12/2015</TestDate>
            <Worked>true</Worked>
        </WorkedInfo>
        <WorkedInfo>
            <TaxTableID>61</TaxTableID>
            <TestDate>03/12/2015</TestDate>
            <Worked>true</Worked>
        </WorkedInfo>
        <WorkedInfo>
            <TaxTableID>61</TaxTableID>
            <TestDate>01/12/2015</TestDate>
            <Worked>true</Worked>
        </WorkedInfo>
        <WorkedInfo>
            <TaxTableID>1</TaxTableID>
            <TestDate>01/12/2015</TestDate>
            <Worked>true</Worked>
        </WorkedInfo>
        <WorkedInfo>
            <TaxTableID>62</TaxTableID>
            <TestDate>02/12/2015</TestDate>
            <Worked>true</Worked>
        </WorkedInfo>
        <WorkedInfo>
            <TaxTableID>63</TaxTableID>
            <TestDate>02/12/2015</TestDate>
            <Worked>true</Worked>
        </WorkedInfo>
        <WorkedInfo>
            <TaxTableID>1</TaxTableID>
            <TestDate>03/12/2015</TestDate>
            <Worked>true</Worked>
        </WorkedInfo>
        <WorkedInfo>
            <TaxTableID>64</TaxTableID>
            <TestDate>02/12/2015</TestDate>
            <Worked>true</Worked>
        </WorkedInfo>
        <WorkedInfo>
            <TaxTableID>64</TaxTableID>
            <TestDate>03/12/2015</TestDate>
            <Worked>true</Worked>
        </WorkedInfo>
        <WorkedInfo>
            <TaxTableID>1</TaxTableID>
            <TestDate>02/12/2015</TestDate>
            <Worked>true</Worked>
        </WorkedInfo>
        <WorkedInfo>
            <TaxTableID>63</TaxTableID>
            <TestDate>01/12/2015</TestDate>
            <Worked>true</Worked>
        </WorkedInfo>
        <WorkedInfo>
            <TaxTableID>62</TaxTableID>
            <TestDate>01/12/2015</TestDate>
            <Worked>true</Worked>
        </WorkedInfo>
        <WorkedInfo>
            <TaxTableID>64</TaxTableID>
            <TestDate>01/12/2015</TestDate>
            <Worked>true</Worked>
        </WorkedInfo>
        <WorkedInfo>
            <TaxTableID>62</TaxTableID>
            <TestDate>03/12/2015</TestDate>
            <Worked>true</Worked>
        </WorkedInfo>
        <WorkedInfo>
            <TaxTableID>61</TaxTableID>
            <TestDate>02/12/2015</TestDate>
            <Worked>true</Worked>
        </WorkedInfo>
    </EmployeeInfo>
    <PaidPreparerInfo>
        <Title>Agent in Fact</Title>
        <Date>03/15/2015</Date>
        <PrintedName>John Doe</PrintedName>
        <PhoneNumber>888-555-5555</PhoneNumber>
        <FaxNumber>775-555-5555</FaxNumber>
        <FEIN>12-3456789</FEIN>
        <Address1>123 Main St</Address1>
        <City>Reno</City>
        <State>NV</State>
        <Zip>89500</Zip>
        <FirmName>ACME Inc</FirmName>
        <EmailAddress>tax_eservice@irs.com</EmailAddress>
    </PaidPreparerInfo>
</PayrollFormInfo>
```

I'd like to parse it into a Map data structure as follows:

```
[{/PayrollFormInfo/FormInfo[1]/ExportDataVersion[1]=100},{/PayrollFormInfo/FormInfo[1]/QBVersion[1]=IFSP},{/PayrollFormInfo/FormInfo[1]/FormSetID[1]=FSDYF},{/PayrollFormInfo/FormInfo[1]/FormID[1]=INWKS941}, etc...]
```

Notice in the XML there are repeating element nodes so they are characterized by their occurrence order with brackets [occurrence number].

I'm confused as how to go about this. This seems like a simple thing to do but I am having much trouble getting this to work, I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Here is what I am doing in Java code:

```
@Test
public void testP() throws Exception, FactoryConfigurationError, Exception {
    File f = new File("xmlDir/example.xml");
    Map<String,String> map = p(f);
    logger.debug("CONTENTS OF MAP: "+Arrays.toString(map.entrySet().toArray()));
}

public Map<String, String> p(File file) throws Exception {

    Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();
    XMLStreamReader xr = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file));

    while(xr.hasNext()) {

        int e = xr.next();
        if (e == XMLStreamReader.START_ELEMENT) {
            String name = xr.getLocalName();
            xr.next();
            String value = null;
            try {
                value = xr.getText().trim();
            } catch (IllegalStateException exep) {
                exep.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (value != null && !value.isEmpty()) {
                map.put(name, value);
            }
        } 
    }
    return map;
}
```

Output:

```
CONTENTS OF MAP: [ExportDataVersion=100, QBVersion=IFSP, FormSetID=FSDYF, FormID=INWKS941, FormDesc=Quarterly Federal Tax Return, FormFilingPeriod=Quarterly, TotalsBreakoutBy=Daily, BeginDate=01/01/2015, EndDate=03/31/2015, EFYes=true, IncludeInstructionSheet=false, CompanyName=PatsFedTaxSemiWeekly20144QRT_CT, LegalName=P #a(9t)-', EmployerID=507754170, IntuitPayrollServiceID=1862684, LegalAddressLine1=Def-ault/ .String, LegalCity=St. Louis, LegalState=CB, LegalZip=06300-0987, MailingAddressLine1=Default String Addr, MailingCity=Greenwich, MailingState=CT, MailingZip=06830, NumberOfEmployees=2, FWTDepositFrequency=SEMI_WEEKLY, ExemptFlag=false, EmployerType=Contributing, FUTAExemptFlag=false, PeriodBeginDate=03/01/2015, PeriodEndDate=03/31/2015, GrossPay=0.00, NetPay=0.00, SocialSecurityWages=46153.86, SocialSecurityLiability=-2861.54, MedicareWages=196153.86, MedicareLiability=-3654.22, FederalWages=189230.76, FederalWithholding=-68440.64, TaxableFUTAWages=0.00, TotalFUTAWages=0.00, FUTALiability=0.00, EIC=0.00, SocialSecurityTips=0.00, TaxTableID=61, TotalWagesAndTips=0.00, TaxableWagesAndTips=164615.44, TaxAmount=0.00, Amount=953.84, PaymentDate=03/27/2015, TestDate=02/12/2015, NumEmps=2, EmployeeID=4514229, FirstName=JoseCT, MiddleInitial=S, LastName=George, SSN=792-93-6215, IsStatutory=false, HasPensionPlan=false, EmployeeType=REGULAR, FederalReturnType=941, HireDate=10/09/2009, NumberOfExemptions=0, StateLived=CT, StateWorked=CT, Gender=M, AddressLine1=123 default St., City=Reno, State=NV, ZipCode=06830, Worked=true, Title=Agent in Fact, Date=03/15/2015, PrintedName=Joe Doe, PhoneNumber=888-555-4444, FaxNumber=775-555-5555, FEIN=12-3456789, Address1=123 Main St, Zip=89500, FirmName=ACME Inc, EmailAddress=tax_eservice@IRS.com]
```

The problem here is that since there are repeating element nodes, my current implementation only captures the 1 occurrence of the element nodes. So if there were a way I could make the keys as XPath, so I could indicate the number of occurrence as [1] or [2] as indicated above, I would not have this problem. That way I can capture all the values.

Any help or assistance would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm removing the [regex] tag as it's unrelated to the question, and it'll save you from copious [lynching](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3764814) ;)

Comment: Thanks for saving me!